# How to get Amazon Lex to respond with voice to a text message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I'm using the Amazon Lex service. My input is always a text message, but sometimes I'd like a spoken response in addition to the text. I configured an output voice in the Lex settings.

I've tried adding a header `amz-lex:accept-content-types=SSML` to the request, but it returns with `Invalid Bot Configuration: No usable messages given the current slot and sessionAttribute set. (Service: AmazonLexRuntime; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException;`. The same request works just fine when I ask for `PlainText`. And even if I ask for `SSML,PlainText` it'll respond with plain text only.

Do I need to configure something else inside Lex to allow it to do voice responses?

Comment: I'm using the AWS Java library to make these requests, but language shouldn't matter so I didn't tag [java].

Comment: First just checking the basics....Are you wrapping the message in SSML `<speak> </speak>` tags? Did you forget the x in `x-amz-lex:accept-content-types`?

Comment: I'm adding the header as stated in the question, but I don't think I added `<speak>` tags in the messages. I'll look into that tomorrow. Will I need to make different messages for speech and non-speech?

Comment: It then also depends on your input/output channel. For example facebook messenger only outputs plainText. AWS Connect outputs voice to phone and will even take a plainText message and output it as voice without needing `<speak>` tags. So, what channel are you using that your want to output voice with?

Comment: @JayA.Little I'm not sure where to add those speak tags. In the AWS Lex console, in the response message? The UI escapes those tags, so that doesn't seem to be the case (and doesn't actually work, I tried). Or in the text message I'm sending to Lex? That also seems strange, as I want a spoken response, not spoken input.

Comment: The channel I'm using is my own Java app ("Return parameters to client"), not something like Slack or Facebook.

Comment: The speak tags are used in the message returned in the response to the Lex request that was sent to your Lambda function. Are you using a Lambda function behind the Lex bot or no Lambda only the Lex console to handle responses? (so many pieces to the puzzle lol)

Comment: @JayA.Little I'm not using a lambda function, just messages defined in fields like `Prompt` (for soliciting slot values) and `Message` (as Response)

Comment: Thanks for answering my Qs to narrow down your problem, I hope my answer provides at least a direction of where you can take it from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lex cannot actually output voice by itself.
Lex will always output a JSON response and that response needs to be processed by the channel the user is accessing Lex with. So that channel is what outputs either text or voice based on how it processes the response message delivered from Lex.

[Amazon Lex](https://aws.amazon.com/lex/) can handle speech-to-text.

[Amazon Polly](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/) can do the reverse: text-to-speech.

If you go to the above Lex page, they have a few examples of using Lex for conversation logic and then Polly for text-to-speech and outputting voice to the user.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then there's one more thing I don't understand: Why does Lex allow me to set a voice and ask for a `SSML` response?

Comment: I'm currently calling Polly separately using the text response from Lex. I expected Lex to be able to do that, either out of the box or via a lambda function, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried Polly yet. I develop with Lex but use the Lambda back-end heavily, so that SSML content-type in the request tells my own back-end code that I should respond with <speak> tags. I don't think the Lex Console does anything based on the content-type, except to make sure that the response message-type matches the accepted content-type, which is what gave you the error. Also, when you want to make your chat bot really powerful, you'll definitely want to use the Lambda function where you can double check what Lex understood and tailor your own dynamic messages back.

Comment: I'm already running a Java app (on EC2), so using a Lambda for that seems kind of pointless...

Comment: Looks like Lex forces you to use Lambda as a middle man in the "Lambda initialization and validation" section of the Lex Console, so I just use it to bridge to my PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize SSML(Speech Synthesis Markup Language) for this, even to test voice in Lex Test Bot Console, using message content-type.

Using SSML tags, you can customize and control aspects of speech, such as pronunciation, volume, and speech rate.

SSML comes with a variety of directives with which you can customize pronunciation and create based on your requirement . Eg - say-as directive

```
`"message": {       
   "contentType": "SSML",
   "content": "<speak> Hi " + data["User ID"].split('.')[0]+", Your Reference Number <say-as interpret-as="characters">" +  "ABC"+event.currentIntent.slots.RefNo+ "</say-as> is ," + data["Status"] +"</speak>"
}`
```

Introduced in 2018 - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/02/announcing-responses-capability-in-amazon-lex-and-ssml-support-in-text-response/